hypothesis testing short term data against long term population with much higher standard deviation - a.k.a. how to test apples v. oranges
Actual question, in as general terms as possible
Suppose that I have a Gaussian superpopulation of known mean and standard deviation. Suppose that I know that this superpopulation is actually a convolution of many subpopulations of known and equal standard deviation; but the subpopulation means are distibuted such that they result in the superpopulation mean and superpopulation standard deviation. This means that I do not know exactly the value of the mean of any randomly drawn subpopulation.
Suppose that I want to test whether my treatment changes the mean w.r.t. the subpopulation. I expect an effect in the order of the standard deviation of the superpopulation. Is there a way to do this? If yes, what method would I use?
Motivation for this question which might help you answer it
I work in a manufacturing operation, and we ran into the following situation.
We want to test whether some parameter (let's say $Y$) improves for some new process. We know from experience that there is a considerable lot-to-lot and supplier-to-supplier and even seasonal variation in our raw material. We see that in the distribution for $Y$, which has a relatively high long term standard deviation $\sigma_{lt}$. We also know that our production process has some variation on the timescale that it takes to perform experiments, but this short term variation is much smaller than the long term variation, let's say $\sigma_{st} \ll \sigma_{lt}$. This holds true even if we don't do any experiments.
Adding a numerical example: Let's say our long term $\mu_{lt} = 0$ with $\sigma_{lt} = 5$, and we have $\sigma_{st} = 1$. We perform a test, and our sample mean is $\overline{y_{test}}$ and sample standard deviation is $s_{test} \approx \sigma_{st}$. It is enticing to compare $\overline{y_{test}}$ against $\mu_{lt} = 0$, but that would be a mistake. We are actually sampling from a distribution of unknown $\mu_{st}$ with $\sigma_{st} = 1$. We know that $\mu_{st}$ is distributed around $\mu_{lt} = 0$, but we don't know its actual value. So, comparing a sample result to the long term population estimates is an apples to oranges comparison.
Some solutions are obvious, and we actually use these when possible:

Ideally we perform paired tests, where we take a sample from the production line, and test on the differences between test sample result and production sample for each pair. Unfortunately, this is often not possible due to practical limitations (mostly related to safety and/or non-existent sampling points). I.e., a "within-apple" comparison.
Our fallback is to run the experiment and reference production in parallel, and perform two-sample tests. We compare a test sample to a sample of the reference population, i.e. a proper apples to apples comparison.

However, we run into cases where this fallback is also not possible. We have a separate line on which we can run small tests, also during times when there is no reference production running. If we expect and observe a large effect ($\gt 10\sigma_{lt}$), there is obviously no need to worry (and little need to support our conclusions with complicated statistical work). Our Type I and II risks will not be entirely accurate, but the practical implications are not particularly important. On the other hand, as the expected small effect is made smaller, down to the order of $\sigma_{lt}$, it will become more and more difficult to distinguish the effect of the treatment from the natural long term variation.
Which techniques are available to be able to detect small changes in a situation as described above?
